# How to test "initialize" method using RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

## github_asset.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'asset_ingester/helpers/project_details'
require 'active_model'

module AssetIngester
  module Asset
    class GithubAsset
      include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON

      attr_reader :id, :name, :full_name, :description, :owner_name, :owner_url,
                  :owner_avatar_url, :url, :html_url, :artifact_id, :jiras, :asset_type

      # Public: Initializes an instance of the GithubAsset class
      #
      # repo        - A hash containing github repository details
      # asset_type  - A string representation of the asset type
      def initialize(repo, asset_type)
        @id = repo[:id]
        @name = repo[:name]
        @full_name = repo[:full_name]
        @description = repo[:description]
        @owner_name = repo.dig(:owner, :login)
        @owner_url = repo.dig(:owner, :url)
        @owner_avatar_url = repo.dig(:owner, :avatar_url)
        @url = repo[:url]
        @html_url = repo[:html_url]
        @asset_type = asset_type
        @artifact_id = repo[:artifact_id] if repo[:artifact_id] && !repo[:artifact_id].empty?
        @jiras = repo[:jiras] if repo[:jiras] && !repo[:jiras].empty?
      end

      # Public: Defines the JSON serialization structure
      #
      # https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#serialization
      def attributes
        {
          'id' => @id,
          'name' => @name,
          'full_name' => @full_name,
          'description' => @description,
          'owner_name' => @owner_name,
          'owner_url' => @owner_url,
          'owner_avatar_url' => @owner_avatar_url,
          'url' => @url,
          'html_url' => @html_url,
          'asset_type' => @asset_type,
          'artifact_id' => @artifact_id,
          'jiras' => @jiras
        }.compact
      end
    end
  end
end
```

## github_asset_spec.rb

```
require 'asset_ingester/asset/github_asset'

RSpec.describe AssetIngester::Asset::GithubAsset, type: :api do
    context "creating" do 
        let(:asset_type) {"node_package"}
        let(:repo) do
            [id: 131_690,
                name: 'acm-care-management-js',
                full_name: 'AcuteCaseManagementUI/acm-care-management-js',
                owner_name: 'AcuteCaseManagementUI',
                owner_url: 'https://github.cerner.com/api/v3/users/AcuteCaseManagementUI',
                owner_avatar_url: 'https://avatars.github.cerner.com/u/4095?',
                url: 'https://github.cerner.com/api/v3/repos/AcuteCaseManagementUI/acm-care-management-js',
                html_url: 'https://github.cerner.com/AcuteCaseManagementUI/acm-care-management-js',
                asset_type: 'node_package',
                artifact_id: "",
                jiras: [] ]
            end

        describe '::attributes' do
            subject { AssetIngester::Asset::GithubAsset.attributes(repo, asset_type) }

            it 'instantiates the class with 2 arguments' do
              expect(subject).to be_an_instance_of(AssetIngester::Asset::GithubAsset)
            end

            it 'sets a to the first argument' do
              expect(subject.repo).to eq(repo)
            end

            it 'sets b to the second argument' do
              expect(subject.asset_type).to eq(asset_type)
            end
          end
    end
end
```

This is how i tried testing the github_asset.rb file but however I'am receiving the following error while defining the subject

AssetIngester::Asset::GithubAsset creating ::attributes instantiates the class with 2 arguments
     Failure/Error: subject { AssetIngester::Asset::GithubAsset.attributes(repo, asset_type) }

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `attributes' for AssetIngester::Asset::GithubAsset:Class
   Did you mean?  attr_writer
```

I am green to RSpec testing and want to know how this can be done.

Comment: BTW, the literal `[id: 131_690]` in `let(:repo)` creates a hash within an array. You probably want `{id: 131_690}` instead, i.e. curly brackets instead of square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You get that `NoMethodError` because you are trying to call `attributes` as a *class method*:

```
subject { AssetIngester::Asset::GithubAsset.attributes(repo, asset_type) }
#                                           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

although in your code, `attributes` is defined as an *instance method*.

But apart from that, you ask *"how ruby initialize method can be tested"* and apparently your test code is all about `initialize` and not about `attributes`, so let's start at the beginning:

```
describe '::attributes' do
  # ...
end
```

You want to test `initialize,` so `attributes` should be `initialize`. And since `initialize` is an instance method (rather than a class method), `::` should be `#`:

```
describe '#initialize' do
  # ...
end
```

And your `subject` should be an instance of `GithubAsset` which is created via [`new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Class.html#method-i-new)<sup>1</sup>:

```
describe '#initialize' do
  subject { AssetIngester::Asset::GithubAsset.new(repo, asset_type) }

  # ...
end
```

With that in place, you can start writing your tests, e.g.:

```
describe '#initialize' do
  subject { AssetIngester::Asset::GithubAsset.new(repo, asset_type) }

  it 'sets the id attribute' do
    expect(subject.id).to eq(131690)
  end
end
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In Ruby, you rarely invoke `::allocate` and `#initialize` directly. So instead of:

```
obj = Array.allocate
obj.send(:initialize, 5) { |i| i ** 2 }
obj #=> [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

you typically just call `new` and let it call `allocate` and `initialize` for you:

```
obj = Array.new(5) { |i| i ** 2 }
obj #=> [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```